# partial sum question

Tags: calculus

find a formula for the $n$th partial sum of the series and use it to find the series' sum if the series converges.
$$2+\frac 23+\frac 29+\frac2{27}+\dots+\frac{2}{3^{n-1}}$$

The answer is $S_n=2\times\frac{1-\left(\frac13\right)^n}{1-\left(\frac 13\right)}$

I just don't understand how the answer was found

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Are you familiar with geometric series?

Answer (score 0):

First notice that $3^2=9$ and $3^3 = 27$. Now we assume the series converges. So, assume the series converges to $S$ for example. We have
$$S = 2 + \frac{2}{3} + \frac{2}{3^2} + \frac{2}{3^3} + \cdots + \frac{2}{3^{n-1}}.$$
Now notice that we can factor out a $1/3$. So we have 
$$S = 2 + \frac{1}{3}\left(2 + \frac{2}{3} + \frac{2}{3^2} + \cdots + \frac{2}{3^{n-2}} \color{blue}{+\frac{2}{3^{n-1}} - \frac{2}{3^{n-1}}}\right).$$
Notice that the terms in blue are just $0$, so it's valid for them to be there. Also notice that the terms in green: 
$$S = 2 + \frac{1}{3}\left(\color{green}{2 + \frac{2}{3} + \frac{2}{3^2} + \cdots + \frac{2}{3^{n-2}} +\frac{2}{3^{n-1}}} - \frac{2}{3^{n-1}}\right)$$
is just $S$! So we have
$$S = 2 + \frac{1}{3}\left(S - \frac{2}{3^{n-1}}\right).$$
The above is just a simple algebra problem. Solve for $S$!